# Getting java sql time and inserting it to a table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, date, timestamp

```
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();         
        java.util.Date now = calendar.getTime();             
        java.sql.Time currentTimestamp = new java.sql.Time(now.getTime());
        Date date = new Date(currentTimestamp.getTime());
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
        java.sql.Date.valueOf(formattedDate);
        System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

How to get the current formatted System time(yyyy-MM-dd) and insert it to the table? I already tried my best and search for the answer but its no good I get different error messages like when I insert `java.sql.Date.valueOf(formattedDate);`I always get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` but when I remove `java.sql.Date.valueOf(formattedDate)` and change this line `"+pcList.get(j).getid()+",0,0` into `"+pcList.get(j).getid()+",0,2014-07-07` I always get an error saying `Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '2000' for column 'date' at row 1`

```
if(ifLoggedIn){
            for(int j=0;j<b;j++){
            try {
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();   
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT MAX(transactionID) from transaction");
                while(rs.next()){                
                   tID = rs.getInt("MAX(transactionID)");
                }                
                tID= tID+1;
                stmt.executeUpdate("Insert into ccpdb.transaction(membershipNum,productID,time,date,paymentOption,amount,transactionID,quantity) values ("+currentuser.getMembershipNum()+","+pcList.get(j).getid()+",0,0,\"west\","+tf1.getText()+","+tID+","+pcList.get(j).f3.getText()+")"
                        + ""); 
                conn.close();
                } catch (Exception g) {
                    System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
                    System.err.println(g.getMessage());
                }   
            }
        }
```

Please help me!!

Answer (score 1):

Just use the database time, rather than the java time.  You can get it using the function `now()` or `CURRENT_DATE`.  I can't quite tell where you want to put this in the `insert`, but it can go in the list of values.

Comment: OH MY GOD THAT WAS AN EASY FIX!! I didn't know that we can do that :((( thanks you just saved me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
java.util.Date now = new java.util.Date();
java.sql.Date insertDate = new java.sql.Date(now.getTime());
```

You can insert this date directly.

You are getting this error as you are trying to save String in date column.